# Selecting boolean in MySQL based on contents of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
Name: Posts

Id Creator Title Body Tags Time
1  1       Test  Test Test 123456789
```

and

```
Name: Action

Id Creator Type Target
1  1       like 1
2  3       like 1
3  2       like 1
4  1       delete 1
```

I'd like to return all the values from the first table and a boolean stating whether there is a record in the other table `WHERE Type='delete'`.

The `Target` field in the second table corresponds to the `Id` in the first table.

I have the following query (which doesn't work). For one thing it returns an instance of the row for each corresponding row in the Action table, even for actions other than 'delete'.

```
SELECT `Posts`.*, IF(`Action`.`Type`='deleted',1,0) AS "Deleted" 
FROM `Posts` JOIN 
     `Action` ON `Action`.`Target` = `Posts`.`Id` 
ORDER BY `Id` DESC;
```

I do not want multiple copies of the row in the first table returned for `Type='like'` or any others apart from `Type='delete'`.

My desired result from this sample:

```
Id Creator Title Body Tags Time Deleted
1  1       Test  Test Test 123456789 1
```

I hope this makes sense and my apologies for such a lengthy question / explanation.

Comment: Any sample and desired result set ?

Comment: You desired result set also needed

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Oops. There we go. Added.

Comment: If this is your desired resultset then whats wrong with the answer given by @lampdev ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Well, his answer returns duplicate rows for each row in the other table where `Type='like'` and if I remove the `WHERE` clause, but if the `WHERE` clause stays, it only returns rows where `Deleted=1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT Posts.*, IF(Action.Id IS NULL,0,1) as Deleted 
FROM Posts 
LEFT JOIN Action 
ON Action.Target = Posts.Id and Type='delete'
```

If you don't care about perfomance

```
SELECT Posts.*,
       exists
  (SELECT 1
   FROM Action
   WHERE Target = Posts.Id
     AND TYPE='delete') AS Deleted
FROM Posts
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see you are using `deleted` while in data set it is `delete`

```
SELECT `Posts`.*,
       IF(`Action`.`Type`='delete',1,0) AS "Deleted"
FROM `Posts`
JOIN `Action` ON `Action`.`Target` = `Posts`.`Id`
WHERE `Action`.`Type` != 'like'
ORDER BY `Id` DESC;
```

Comment: That excludes all results in the first table that have the 'like' action in the other table. I'd still like to select those but just with `Deleted = 0`. However, if I remove the `WHERE` clause from that, it returns duplicate rows for each `'like'`.